# What might be causing UDP packets to be dropped?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, datagram

I'm using udp protocol to do a video conference application for a client. I use a server with a public IP to get the udp public ports and get behind each clients NAT. With packets smaller than ~500bytes everything works great but when I try to send bigger packets and they get fragmented they don't arrive at the destination.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you somehow have the no-fragment bit set? UDP does work best on small packets (fragmentation and reassembly take time). The nature of UDP is that it has no guarantees. If you need guaranteed delivery or guaranteed order of delivery, you need to use TCP. If fragmented UDP packets arrive with missing or out of order fragments, the packet won't be reassembled and will be dropped.

Comment: You mean set the socket not to fragment packets? How do I go about sending frames of ~2kb? Should I separate each frame into 4 different packets and do the reassembly myself? I'm asking because of the udp mtu. I read that usually is about 500b right? What should I do to send a frame from one client and sucessfully receive it on the other client when it is bigget than the udp mtu?